# Android Studio doesn't see some .java files that are present in the SDK directory

Tags: android

I built a custom `Android ROM` that supports `A2DP Sink` and `AVRCP` bluetooth profiles which are disabled by default.
Now i want to build an app that exploits these profiles, i found that the required files (`BluetoothA2DPSink.java` and `BluetoothAVRCPCpntroller.java`) are already present in android `SDK` folder ( from 21 and up).
The problem is "`import android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dpSink;`" doesn't work, `Android studio` is unable to see these files.
I guess as these `Bluetooth` profiles aren't enabled in standard `Android` builds the files are there but arent included.
What do I do to include them in the `SDK` ?

Comment: Try updating your SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files I need aren't included in the android.jar
I have to build an SDK that includes them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to modified android.jar that will allow you to use hidden apis:
https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api